# Extract data from xml file (python)

Tags: python, xml

I want to extract some data from the xml file (xmldoc): `<chart><series><value xid=\'0\'>2/01/2011</value>...`.

I could extract the date '2/01/2011' with the following code:

```
chart= xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('chart')[0]
series= chart.getElementsByTagName('series')[0]
Dates=[]
for element in series.getElementsByTagName('value'):
    Dates.append(element.firstChild.data)
```

But I can't get the 'xid' value ('0' here). How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you appear to be using the `xml.dom.minidom` module, you need to look at the [DOM level 1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/) to see what API is implemented. For attribute access, elements have a [`getAttribute()` method](https://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html#method-getAttribute):

```
element.getAttribute("xid")
```

However, the DOM is a *terrible* API to use. It is designed to be the lowest common denominator between a wide range of programming languages. For XML handling, the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) is a lot friendlier:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)  # or ET.fromstring()
dates = []
for element in tree.findall('.//series/value'):  # all <value> elements in <series> elements
    xid = element.attrib['xid']  # attribute access via the .attrib dictionary
    date = element.text  # the text data in the element
```

You can also look at the [lxml library](https://lxml.de/index.html) for a more powerful implementation of the ElementTree API, such as additional XPath query support.